# Creation of dynamic datafields cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp

I have planned to create tables for dynamic datafields. My concept is to store a dynamic form data inside tables(MySQL). The user can select any number of fields(datatypes) from form.The form is a dynamic form one seen in [here](http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/)  . How can we design dB in order to save user's data dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just allow for fields within the database to be null. That way when you save the form if any fields have not been filled it doesn't throw an error

Comment: Allowing fields to be null and saving serialized data in fields can be a better option. But we cannot apply it easily for dynamic forms.Since we don't know how much fields that table should have. I think we should follow EAV model or similar to work on dynamic forms. Not pretty much sure about it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you need to implement EAV data model [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) Also, there are some ready solutions

- [some project on github](https://github.com/search?q=cakephp-eav)
- [EAV behaviour on bakery, also one of project from github](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/abalonepaul/2011/10/11/eav_behavior)
- [expandable behaviour](http://debuggable.com/posts/unlimited-model-fields-expandable-behavior:48428c2e-9a88-47ec-ae8e-77a64834cda3)